# How to handle multiple answers in SPSS

Tags: spss

I am having a questionnaire and I am trying to analyze it in the SPSS, the question is:
What are the benefits of the Implementation:
1. Fast
2. Time Saving.
3.Reduce Cost.

How to handle this in SPSS.

I have created a variable called Benefits and in the values, I added them. Now, in the Data View how to choose multiple answers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to treat this as a multiple response question.  It could be a multiple dichotomy where you have a yes/no variable for each possible response.  Alternatively it could be a  multiple response set where you list the first k responses.  The Custom Tables option provides the most flexibility here, but there is also a MULT RESPONSE procedure in the Base if you don't have Custom Tables.  The Chart Builder can also handle multiple response sets.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE HELP IN WHAT ARE THE STEPS TO DO THAT

Comment: If you have Custom Tables, start with Analyze>Tables>Multiple Response Sets.  If you don't you can still use Data>Define Multiple Response Sets and then use the Chart Builder for graphics.  And with just the Base, you can use Analze > Multiple Response.  Just note that the mult response sets define with the first options mentioned are different from and incompatible with the sets used in the last option.  So if you are going to use via Analze > Multiple Response, be sure to define the sets there.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not the "sophisticated way" but...

If I understand your question correct: 1. you want to now, how to add these values into SPSS and 2. You want to know, how to work with this data.
Actually by 3 value options you have 9 groups: 1. fast AND time saving AND reduce cost; 2. fast AND time saving NO reduced costs; 3. fast No time saving No reduced costs... and so to group 9: NO fast NO time saving NO reduce costs.

1: SPSS is similar to excel. In the "variable view" (below, left) you create a new variable, e.g. "Benefits". Then you click on "Label" and write "1" for "fast/time saving/reduce costs", "2" for "fast/timesaving", 3 for...
Then you go to "data view" and enter the corresponding values.
2: At the end you will have 9 groups and can perform an ANOVA test. Or you can "recode" the "Benefits" variable to a set of dummy variables, such as "fast" whereby every group which contained the anser "fast" is coded as "1" and the rest as "0"; and so on.

I hope it helps!
Best,
Eugene